# Converting OracleDbType.Date to Date is not valid

Tags: vb.net, oracle, odp.net

I am trying to do the following from an `OracleCommand.Parameter`:

Stored procedure:

```sql
PROCEDURE GetDate(inParam IN VARCHAR2, outDate OUT DATE) AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT MAX(DateVal) INTO outDate
        FROM Table1
        WHERE Col1 = inParam;
    EXCEPTION 
        WHEN no_data_found THEN
        outDate:= NULL;
END GetDate;
```

```vb
Dim returnDate as Date?

Using Connection = New OracleConnection(connectionString)
Using Command As OracleCommand = Connection.CreateCommand()

Connection.Open()
Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
Command.CommandText = "GEN_PACKAGE.GetDate"
Command.Parameters.Add("inParam", inParam).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
Command.Parameters.Add("outDate", OracleDbType.Date).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
Command.ExecuteNonQuery()

If Not CType(Command.Parameters("outDate").Value, INullable).IsNull Then
    returnDate = CDate(Command.Parameters("outDate").Value)
End If

End Using
End Using
```

However it throws the following exception:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll 
>   Additional information: Conversion from type 'OracleDate' to type 'Date' is not valid.

What is the point of `OracleDbType.Date` if it cannot be converted to a .NET `Date` type? How can I take my `OracleDbType.Date` and pass it out of my function as a .NET `Date` (or Date?, I've tried both)?

Comment: Did you simply try `returnDate = Command.Parameters("Date").Value`

Comment: Does your OracleCommand return really a `DATE` (or `TIMESTAMP`) or a **string**?

Comment: OracleCommand returns an OracleDbType.Date, hence the exception "Conversion from type 'OracleDate' to type 'Date' is not valid.".

I did try without the cast, but Option Strict doesn't like the implicit conversion. Which is probably a good thing because if it can't do it explicitly I doubt it would handle it implicitly.

Comment: Please show us the OracleCommand and the PL/SQL function/procedure if existing.

Comment: I've edited the code in as requested.

Comment: It doesn't appear that you have a parameter called `Date` in your parameters collections.  Perhaps you meant `outDate` instead?  Can you post the exact error message and on which line the error is thrown?

Comment: You don't assign any value to input parameter `inParam - is this by intention?

Comment: Apologies, in order to post the code online I had to make some of the variable names generic and I didn't use the same ones (ironic, I know). I've amended. The `inParam` is a string passed into the function.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is biggest misconception (that I often seen from ODP usages) that here

```
Command.Parameters("outDate").Value
```

you simply retrieve a CLR type. In reality, you get `OracleDate` - [see this](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/OracleDateStructure.htm#ODPNT4819)

So the code to retrieve the value would be

```
dim dotNetVal as DateTime = Command.Parameters("outDate").Value.Value
```

And to check for NULL you do

```
if Command.Parameters("outDate").Value.IsNull then
```

Yes, this cast -

```
CDate(Command.Parameters("outDate").Value)
```

is invalid because you can't cast `OracleDate` into `DateTime`